# Is it possible to convert TLC SSD to SLC at the expense of cutting out the capacity?

Tags: windows, ssd, usb-flash-drive, conversion, usb-storage

3d TLC SSDs are good for use as daily driver these days, compared to planar TLC.
But still TLC is TLC no matter how you call it, writing 3 bits in each cell.

A few days ago I heard about P-SLC, short for Pseudo-SLC nand flash technology, which writes just one bit in each cell, as if it is SLC(single level cell) memory chips, which theoretically increase P/E cycles almost equivalent to genuine SLC. Even if it does not reach the same endurance that genuine SLC can have, the price/GB is much lower in comparison, making it quite a good deal.

But I can't find a way HOW to convert TLC to pSLC with the help of software, let alone if that kind of software exists.

Any help would be so beneficial to those who try to DIY the cost effective item on their own.

Comment: Unless the drive itself has some kind of support for this (like a firmware mode change), I doubt that it is possible.

Comment: I think you need manufacturer support for that, though many TLC drives use part of the drive in SLC mode. Whlle they have spare capacity in the SLC part writes are fast, and when they run out performance degrades significantly.  Usually the buffer is large enough for normal operations, and during idle it can 'optimize' by copying SLC bufffer stored data to TLC cells.

Comment: Which means that if you can find a drive where you can set these value with a manufacturers toolbox you might almost archive your goal (e.g. set buffer to 99%, SLC speed archived, but not durability since on idle with will reoptimize)

Comment: Very good question. I would like to know some useful answer too. Obviously you need special firmware designed for a specific SSD models that does exactly that - program only fast pages of MLC/TLC/QLC and announce the capacity that correspond to 1 bit-per-cell. This way you have both speed and endurance benefits at the cost of 2x(MLC)/3x(TLC)/4x(QLC) capacity reduction. The useful answer obviously would be a link to that custom firmware for some specific models available for sale and link to MP-tool that can upload it to SSD.